# Looking for a specific word for repentive action?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

One possible usage of the word is 
*As ____ for stealing the house, he made them chocolate cookies*

It's a word for something positive/good that you do to *right* a prior *wrong* you may have committed.

The word probably starts with 'r'. It's a single word. And if I recall right, it's an -ion abstract noun.

Edit: The word might be used in religious contexts too. 
As ___ for his mistakes, he planted a tree.

Comment: Are you looking for "***recompense***"?

Comment: Pretty sure 'restitution' is what you're thinking of

Comment: The word for an expression of repentance is _penance_. "For your penance, say three 'Our Father's, three 'Hail Mary's, and a good 'Act of Contrition'." The issue of recompense is separate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not looking for penance. And mostly not recompense/recompensation either?

Comment: @Yaitzme I'm pretty sure that penance works here. Why do you say that that is not what you're looking for?

Comment: i got to 'retribution' - you haven't stated as to whether the punishment was self-inflicted

Comment: @Mitch - Sorry, but I should have been clearer. I have a specific word in mind that I was looking for rather than just a word that fits the definition.

Comment: Ah, specific versus non-specific indefinites. _She's looking for a policeman, but she can't find him_ (specific); versus _She's looking for a policeman, but she can't find one_ (non-specific).

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - Retribution! That's the word I was looking for ! Thanks a ton! Although, I just did understand that the meanings I gave were incorrect and misleading.

Comment: *Retribution* usually means something inflicted upon a wrong-doer as an act of vengeance, not something wrong-doers take upon themselves, as implied in your examples.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options. Here are the ones that start with "r".

[**Reparation**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reparation) 
[rep-uh-rey-shuh n] noun
1. the making of amends for wrong or injury done:
reparation for an injustice.
2. compensation in money, material, labor, etc., payable by a defeated country to another country or to an individual for loss suffered during or as a result of war.

[**Restitution**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/restitution)
[res-ti-too-shuh n, -tyoo-] noun
1. reparation made by giving an equivalent or compensation for loss, damage, or injury caused; indemnification.

Another option:

[**Indemnify**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indemnify)
[in-dem-nuh-fahy] verb (used with object), indemnified, indemnifying.
1. to compensate for damage or loss sustained, expense incurred, etc.

Comment: I am getting it now, "restitution" seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

**"compensation"** comes to mind.

> - "something that is done or given to make up for damage, trouble,
>   something good that acts as a balance against something bad or undesirable." -  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compensation)

"As a compensation for stealing, he made them chocolate cookies."

I would also suggest **"requital"** -

> - "something to make up for loss or damage" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/requital)
> - "The judge ordered the landlord to pay his former tenants $100,000 each as requital for goods lost or damaged in the apartment fire."